# Can't connect to Facebook via Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

I'm trying to connect to facebook from my iOS application, so I can make a wall-post.
I've tried using Sharekit, and also the Facebook mobile API.

Using the 'stable' Sharekit, I can connect, but I'm lacking features I need with that version.
So I've tried using the latest Sharekit from GIT, with no luck.

After providing my facebook login information, I always receive an error of the following flavour:

***"This page contains the following errors: 'error on line 2 at column 75: EntityRef: expecting ';'"***

Occasionally I'll get a different line # or slightly different error message, but there's always an EntityRef problem on a line/column.

Giving up on that, I tried using the facebook mobile SDK and have the exact same problem.

I then tried the facebook sample app, and have the same problem.

I've setup a facebook app account, and I've specified that AppID (247969245245487) in all the place I believe I need to:

static NSString* kAppId = @"247969245245487" in the sample app's appdelegate

**#define SHKFacebookAppID          @"247969245245487" in SHKConfig.h for Sharekit.**

Likewise, I've got the following in the info.plist for both apps:

```
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fb247969245245487</string>
    </array>
```

I'm using XCode 4.0.2.

I'm at a bit of a loss here... any tips or thoughts on where I could start debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same problem, and I'm not sure what's changed on Facebook's end that causes the problem, but I do believe it's on their end. That said I did find a "solution" that worked for my customers:

1. If your simulator or device has the Facebook Mobile app installed, an updated version was recently made available on the app store. When I updated to that latest version, the problem went away for me.
2. When the simulator or device doesn't have the official Facebook app installed, the iOS SDK (for me) doesn't generate the same error.

So again, I only experienced it on devices that had the Facebook app installed, and then the problem was "fixed" when I updated to the latest version of that app. Maybe this'll work for you too?

Comment: Argh! Thanks guys, upgrading (or uninstalling) the facebook app fixed the problem.